# Can't Figure Out How To Use AutoMapper With Post Action In RESTful Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have a simple RESTful API and this is the post route handler I'm trying to apply AutoMapper in:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateHotel([FromBody]Hotel hotelCreateDto)
    {
        var hotel = _mapper.Map<Hotel>(hotelCreateDto);

        var createdHotel = await _hotelService.CreateHotel(hotel);

        var hotelReadDto = _mapper.Map<HotelReadDto>(createdHotel);

        return CreatedAtAction("GetHotelById", new { id = hotelReadDto.Id }, hotelReadDto);
    }
```

So in the request I get a hotelCreateDto which looks like that:

```
 public class HotelCreateDto
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and I map this to Hotel entity:

```
public class Hotel
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and a new hotel object is created in the next line. However when hotelReadDto is going to be assigned to the new mapped object, a 500 error occurs: "*AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.*"

Could you catch a mistake here? I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Edit: there'S also this things after the error above: "Mapping types:
Object -> HotelReadDto
System.Object -> HotelFinder.DTO.DTOs.HotelReadDto"

Edit2: Here is the code in the Configure Services:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

And in the Profile class:

```
public class HotelProfile : Profile
{
    public HotelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Hotel, HotelReadDto>();
        CreateMap<HotelCreateDto, Hotel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `exception.ToString()`, it's telling you _exactly_ what's wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the response in postman.

Comment: Some important parts of your code is missing (HotelReadDto, _mapper)

Comment: Is your mapper configuration setup correctly?  Are you using a MapperConfiguration or Profile  with a call to CreateMap<Hotel, HotelReadDto>?  https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Comment: I'm using a profile with two CreateMap calls. <Hotel, HotelReadDto> and <HotelCreateDto, Hotel>

Comment: And in Configure Services there's this line of code: 
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

Comment: One thing. When you say `[FromBody]Hotel hotelCreateDto`, why type Hotel? I see that the class HotelCreateDto doesn't inherit from Hotel. So, the parameter can't be of type Hotel...

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your services in startup :

it's reusable and cleaner

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

add these interface and class in your project

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        private void ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
        {
                var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i =>i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Mapping")
                    ?? type.GetInterface("IMapFrom`1").GetMethod("Mapping");

                methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });

            }
        }
    }
```

and your dto be like this (map hotel to HotelDto):

```
 public class HotelCreateDto : IMapFrom<HotelCreateDto>
    {
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<Hotel,HotelCreateDto>();
        }
    }
```